# How do I display the .length of an array with a specific category in an angular application

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a set of tabs that show the amount of items in each container that the tabs open. You will see that filter below. And I want to show the amount of objects inside `filtered.length` I suppose.

Here is my Data:

```
[
{
  "img":"assets/images/gallery/girls-1.jpg",
  "group": "girls",
  "title": "Image 1",
  "desc": "Description",
  "link":""
},
{
  "img":"assets/images/gallery/girls-2.jpg",
  "group": "girls",
  "title": "Image 2",
  "desc": "Description",
  "link":""
},
{
  "img":"assets/images/gallery/girls-3.jpg",
  "group": "girls",
  "title": "Image 3",
  "desc": "Description",
  "link":""
},
{
  "img":"assets/images/gallery/music-1.jpg",
  "group": "music",
  "title": "Image 4",
  "desc": "Description",
  "link":""
},
{
  "img":"assets/images/gallery/music-2.jpg",
  "group": "music",
  "title": "Image 5",
  "desc": "Description",
  "link":""
},
{
  "img":"assets/images/gallery/music-3.jpg",
  "group": "music",
  "title": "Image 6",
  "desc": "Description",
  "link":""
},
{
  "img":"assets/images/gallery/music-4.jpg",
  "group": "music",
  "title": "Image 7",
  "desc": "Description",
  "link":""
},
{
  "img":"assets/images/gallery/music-5.jpg",
  "group": "music",
  "title": "Image 8",
  "desc": "Description",
  "link":""
},
{
  "img":"assets/images/gallery/nature-1.jpg",
  "group": "nature",
  "title": "Image 9",
  "desc": "Description",
  "link":""
},
{
  "img":"assets/images/gallery/nature-2.jpg",
  "group": "nature",
  "title": "Image 10",
  "desc": "Description",
  "link":""
},
{
  "img":"assets/images/gallery/nature-3.jpg",
  "group": "nature",
  "title": "Image 11",
  "desc": "Description",
  "link":""
},
{
  "img":"assets/images/gallery/nature-4.jpg",
  "group": "nature",
  "title": "Image 12",
  "desc": "Description",
  "link":""
},
{
  "img":"assets/images/gallery/nature-5.jpg",
  "group": "nature",
  "title": "Image 13",
  "desc": "Description",
  "link":""
},
{
  "img":"assets/images/gallery/nature-6.jpg",
  "group": "nature",
  "title": "Image 14",
  "desc": "Description",
  "link":""
},
{
  "img":"assets/images/gallery/nature-7.jpg",
  "group": "nature",
  "title": "Image 15",
  "desc": "Description",
  "link":""
},
{
  "img":"assets/images/gallery/space-1.jpg",
  "group": "space",
  "title": "Image 16",
  "desc": "Description",
  "link":""
},
{
  "img":"assets/images/gallery/space-2.jpg",
  "group": "space",
  "title": "Image 17",
  "desc": "Description",
  "link":""
}
]
```

Here is a screnshot of the page. **Focus on that number in each tab**. That numbers shows how many images are in that category and subsequently, that's how many will show up on the right side. But that part is already done. I just want to show those numbers programmatically.

[image]

And here is my Filtered HTML

```
   <ul ng-init="tab = 1" class="list-group">
        <li ng-class="{active:panel.isSelected(1)}">
            <a class="list-group-item" ng-click="panel.selectTab(1); groupFilter = {}">All
            <span class="badge badge-primary">{{galleries.length}}</span></a>
        </li>
        <li ng-class="{active:panel.isSelected(2)}">
            <a class="list-group-item" ng-click="panel.selectTab(2); groupFilter ={group:'nature'}">Nature
            <span class="badge badge-success"><!--The amount of items of group Nature. 7 --></span></a>
        </li>
        ...


  </ul>
```

Thanks in advance guys. Teaching myself Angular.

Comment: With lodash it is as simple as `_.countBy($scope.category_array,'group');`

Comment: and how is that implemented

Comment: I wasn't quite correct with the lodash countyBy syntax `_.countBy($scope.category_array,'girls','group');` would count of girls. If you need all the counts I posted the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$scope.categoryLength = function(category) {
  var count = 0;
    angular.forEach($scope.category_array, function(item){
        count += item.group == category ? 1 : 0;
    });
    return count; 
}
```

Call the function as:

```
{{categoryLength("nature")}}
```

It gives the length of the group you passed to the function.

Comment: It's not working for me, It gives me all zeroes. Is it becasue I need to replace categories with groups?

Comment: What is your array name? Here "category_array" is a array name, "category" passed to a function is a string i.e "nature","girls" etc.. , .group is a field name.

Comment: Awesome! Worked like a charm!

Comment: @PrabhuChaitanyavarma how to achieve this in angular 8 ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60629462/angular-after-search-result-how-do-i-display-the-length-of-an-array-with-a-sp

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
var counts ={};
for(var i = 0 ; i < items.length ; i++) {
  counts[items[i].group] = counts[items[i].group] ?   counts[items[i].group]+1 : 1;
}
console.log(counts);
```

This will print

```
{ girls: 3, music: 5, nature: 7, space: 2 }
```